# How do I refer to a client_deploy.wsdd file that's in WEB-INF?

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, axis

A basic question, but I can't seem to find the answer.

I have an Axis-generated web service that also calls another web service (for which the stubs are also generated with Axis). It's deployed in weblogic 9.2

That called web service requires authentication.

I've googled for the code to set up authentication. It requires that I set up a client_deploy.wsdd file which I've done, and added it to WEB-INF.

I need to specify this flle to Axis. There seem to be several ways of doing this, including

```
 System.setProperty("axis.ClientConfigFile", "client_deploy.wsdd")
```

or

```
 EngineConfiguration config = new FileProvider("client_deploy.wsdd");
```

but these aren't working for me. Is the issue the path for the client_deploy.wsdd file? How do I refer to a file that's at the top level of the WEB-INF directory? Googling tells me how to access it as a stream, but I don't want that, I need to pass a file name to these functions...

Please point out the obvious that I have missed

Update: Googling suggests this might work

```
HttpServlet servlet = (HttpServlet) MessageContext.
   getCurrentContext().
   getProperty(HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLET);
EngineConfiguration config = new FileProvider(servlet.
   getServletContext().
   getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/client_deploy.wsdd"));
```

Update2: Yep, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just package your custom .WSDD file into a jar and it should work fine. I just tried it :)